# ASP NET 5 Web Application Deployment on IIS

Tags: iis, deployment, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm trying to deploy an ASP NET 5 Web App on IIS but there´s no way to make it works, it gives me the following error:

> Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework
>   'DNX,Version=v4.5.1': ....(a list with all the dependencies of my
>   project)

It seems thats is unable to resolve the path to the dependencies, but if I check on 'approot' folder they are all there.
My 'project.json' is this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "7.0.1",
    "System.Xml.XmlDocument": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
},

"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},

"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }       
}
```

Also the paths from web.config in 'wwwroot' folder seems to be ok:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta4" />
  <add key="runtime-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
  <add key="dnx-version" value="1.0.0-beta4" />
  <add key="dnx-clr" value="clr" />
  <add key="dnx-app-base" value="..\approot\src\Astarte" />
</appSettings>
```

I'm really stucked, ¿any idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use beta4 bits? It's a pretty old release - beta7 is the latest stable.

Comment: Just because the upgrade to beta 6 or 7 has deep breaking changes with Entity Framework 7. Definitily I will upgrade it soon, but right now I need to deploy this version on production server as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to specify the version of the sdk you require (in your case 1.0.0-beta4). Try adding a global.json file in your appication root with the following:

```
{
    "sdk": { "version": "1.0.0-beta4" }
}
```

*On a side note, as @Henk Mollema has said you should probably upgrade at some point to a more recent beta, as beta4 is now quite old. Please beware however that this will cause breaking changes so you may want to tackle this separately!

Comment: Thanks @corkington, I already have this global.json in folder 'approot'. It looks like that:
`code`
{
  "projects": [
    "Astarte",
    "TestAstarte"
  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta4"
  },
  "packages": "packages"
}
`code`

About upgrade to recent beta I prefer not to do it for the moment because it will break lot of stuff. I just want to deploy it on IIS at it is.

Comment: Finally the problem was about the structure of the project. The file global.json MUST be with your .sln file outside the project folder. Is a silly thing but it breaks all the dependencies, so be careful, it was close to drive me mad.